# If someone was in another's memory, wouldn't they see it from that person's perspective?

Tags: pacific-rim

In Pacific Rim shouldn't Raleigh have seen Mako's memory from her perspective since he was never there in the first place?

Comment: The answer is obviously no. That's *not* what happened, so in the universe of the movie that isn't what should have happened. I suspect (hope) that the question you're actually asking is "Why did Raleigh see Mako's memory from his perspective even though he was never there?"

Comment: Out of universe, this is a common problem that I find particularly irritating: memories that aren't from the perspective of the subject, CCTV that's not from a security camera, recordings from an impossible angle, etc. While there may be an in-universe answer, the "real" answer is the director didn't want to do another shot (or put positively, liked the shot the way it was).

Comment: This is due to the work being an "art" and not a documentary. There are theatrical and literary devices at use besides technological ones.

Comment: @Matt I wholly agree. It usually speaks to sloppy film-making.

Comment: @Gorchestopher H, I have a hard time believing that reusing the shot was the most "artistic" decision that could have been made.

Comment: @Matt "Art" simply meaning "non-science".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if we had technology today to view someone else's memories, it would be from the person's perspective.  But "Pacific Rim" is a movie, so I assume someone made the decision to view the memories from a third person perspective, instead of first person.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever two pilots are going through a typical Neural Handshake, we can assume that they "live through" the other pilot's memories (in an instant, if not in a heartbeat).

This can be further believed when Raleigh looks at Mako at the end of their calibration: he was standing on the right and looked on his left, which was exactly what his brother Yancy did before dying (which is why he started taking the rabbit, since it was his last drifting experience).

However, the fact that we see Raleigh inside Mako's memory doesn't forcefully mean that he's experiencing it from a third person perspective. They may have wanted to emphasize on the fact that Raleigh was inside Mako's head without actually being in there.

She could hear him talking to her. He was right aside her, despite not actually being there in her memory. And showing him standing aside her was a way to put the viewers in Mako's shoes (or in her remaining shoe, so to speak).